# Connection Reset on long urls ($_GET) WAMP

Tags: url, post, yii, get, connection

I have an application under Yii, and I have this problem regarding my urls.

With the Yii CGridView, when we filter, the application passes an ajax GET request to the server in a form of a very long url. example:

> http://site.com/reports/default/index/MEmailrequestsList%5Bid%5D//MEmailrequestsList%5Bname%5D//MEmailrequestsList%5Bperson%5D//MEmailrequestsList%5Bemail%5D//MEmailrequestsList%5Bcreated%5D//MEmailrequestsList%5Busersender%5D/josalie/MEmailrequestsList%5Bstatus%5D//MEmailrequestsList_page/2/ajax/reportsgrid?ajax=reportsgrid

With Firefox or Chrome's firebug, it doenst show any errors, just a failed status. Upon reviewing, it gives off a status of connection reset.

I am running the application in Windows, under WAMP.

With other urls (non yii) (

> http://site.com/samplepage/?id=1&poads=2&asd=1&poads=2&asd=1&poads=2&asd=1&poads=2&asd=1&poads=2&asd=1&poads=2&asd=1&poads=2&asd=1&poads=2&asd=1&poads=2&asd=1&poads=2&asd=1&poads=2&asd=1&poads=2&asd=1&poads=2&asd=1&poads=2&asd=1&poads=2&asd=1&poads=2&asd=1&poads=2&asd=1&poads=2&asd=1&poads=2&asd=1&poads=2&asd=1&poads=2&asd=1&poads=2&asd=1&poads=2&asd=1&poads=2&asd=1&poads=2&asd=1&poads=2&asd=1&poads=2&asd=1&poads=2&asd=1&poads=2&asd=1&poads=2&asd=1&poads=2&asd=1&poads=2&asd=1&poads=2&asd=1&poads=2&asd=1&poads=2&asd=1...

)

Comment: Url is not that long to make problem, maybe problem is double slash `//`, this is more likely to be server configuration related, rather than Yii. The other part of your question "With other urls (non yii) (", seems like unfinished sentence? You mean that with other urls it works fine?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. It works on other urls not under Yii.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I did it.

I managed to fix the issue by making the URL of the paginations to use the default get parameter url symbols (? and &). I did this by placing a **'appendParams'=>FALSE** to the UrlManager of the application.

It is fixed now and hopefully somebody will find this helpful.